# What does it mean to say "the fundamental physics is contained in..."?

Tags: terminology

This is very common to show up in books. Here's one example from Thomson's Modern Particle Physics. When talking about the general expression for the $a \rightarrow 1+2$ relativistic decay $$\Gamma_{fi}=\frac{p^*}{32\pi^2m^2_a}\int|M_{fi}|^2d\Omega$$ he says that **the fundamental physics is contained in the** (Lorentz invariant) matrix element.
What does this mean?

Comment: He means that's the important part. Everything else in that equation is a bunch of annoying kinematic factors, which don't depend on the actual nature of the interaction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about communication (or mis-communication). It asks what a particular author is trying to convey by a popular phrase.  Answering does not require the application of physics, only the conventions of science communication.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamental physics , as the comment by knzhou says, is the mathematical formulation for the interaction.

The [matrix element](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/fermi.html) contains the wavefunctions and the potential that gave rise to the interaction under study. This is for simple transitions, but the logic is the same even for the complicated [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model_(mathematical_formulation)) of particle physics with all the three interactions.